# Android Landscape mode cutting off my Layout on bootom

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-tablayout

**I am facing problem .Please see the screen shoot  **
[Android Landscape mode cutting off my bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGUBp.jpg)

**And i want this**

[overlap my sendbox view on tab  layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzNll.jpg)

**My sendbox layout XML code is **

```
<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/sendbox"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/sdboxx"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="330dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="2mm"
        android:id="@+id/headerportion"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2mm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="2mm"
        >
       <!-- android:shadowColor="#ffff"
        android:shadowDx="0.5"
        android:shadowDy="0.5"
        android:shadowRadius="0.5"-->
        <TextView
            android:shadowColor="#ffff"

            android:shadowRadius="1"
            android:textSize="3mm"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textColor="#3951a3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/hide"
            android:text="Hide"
            />
        <TextView

            android:shadowColor="#ffff"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="1"
            android:textSize="3mm"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#603913"
            android:text="MANHATTAN"
            />
        <TextView
            android:shadowColor="#ffff"

            android:shadowRadius="1"
            android:textSize="3mm"

            android:id="@+id/upper_search_text"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="#3951a3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_below="@+id/upper_search_text"
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#603913"

            />
        <TextView
            android:shadowColor="#ffff"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="1"
            android:id="@+id/bigtext"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="3.5mm"
            android:textColor="#603913"
            android:text="Can I Park Here ?"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="2mm"
            android:layout_marginRight="2mm"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bigtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/house_number"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:hint="Number"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:layout_weight=".75"
                    android:layout_width="12mm"
                    android:layout_height="3.5mm"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"/>
                <EditText

                    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                    android:id="@+id/street_full_name"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:hint="Street Full Name"
                    android:layout_weight=".75"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1mm"
                    android:layout_width="30mm"
                    android:layout_height="3.5mm"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <TextView

                    android:shadowColor="#ffff"
                    android:shadowDx="1"
                    android:shadowDy="1"
                    android:shadowRadius="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1mm"
                    android:text="Number"
                    android:layout_weight=".75"
                    android:layout_width="10mm"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#603913"
                    android:textSize="2mm"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <TextView

                    android:shadowColor="#ffff"
                    android:shadowDx="1"
                    android:shadowDy="1"
                    android:shadowRadius="1"
                    android:textSize="2mm"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#603913"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Street Full  Name"
                    android:layout_weight=".75"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7mm"
                    android:layout_width="28mm"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView

                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:id="@+id/datepiker"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:hint="   02/10/17 8:27PM"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="3.5mm" />
            <TextView
                android:shadowColor="#ffff"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="1"
                android:textSize="1mm"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#603913"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date(MM/DD/YY)  Hour(1-12)AM/PM"

                />
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="@drawable/textview_bg"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                ><!-- <<<-&#45;&#45;&#45;&#45;&#45;&#45;added this line

               >-->
               <!-- android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"-->

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/result"
                    android:textColor="#323232"



                    />
            </ScrollView>

            />

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:textSize="2mm"
                android:shadowColor="#ffff"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="1"
                android:textColor="#030000"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="For more detail information,"
                android:textStyle="bold"

                />
            <TextView
                android:textSize="2mm"
                android:shadowColor="#ffff"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="1"
                android:textColor="#030000"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Please refer to map symbols."
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>




<!--end send box-->
```

*i am using tab layout in my main activity  and  i want to overlap my sendbox view on tabbar .*

**it is my Mapfragment xml **

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/Mapfrag"
    tools:context=".Fragments.MapFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:background="@drawable/mapbg"
        app:zoomLevel="12.8"
        app:centerLat="40.7694"
        app:centerLng="-73.9597"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/p_massge"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/p_symblee"
        android:layout_width="7mm"
        android:layout_height="7mm"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:id="@+id/stare"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:src="@drawable/favoritetowx"
        android:layout_width="7mm"
        android:layout_height="7mm"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />

   <!-- send boxx  

    -->


    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/sendbox"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/sdboxx"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="330dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="2mm"
            android:id="@+id/headerportion"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2mm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2mm"
            >
           <!-- android:shadowColor="#ffff"
            android:shadowDx="0.5"
            android:shadowDy="0.5"
            android:shadowRadius="0.5"-->
            <TextView
                android:shadowColor="#ffff"

                android:shadowRadius="1"
                android:textSize="3mm"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:textColor="#3951a3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/hide"
                android:text="Hide"
                />
            <TextView

                android:shadowColor="#ffff"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="1"
                android:textSize="3mm"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#603913"
                android:text="MANHATTAN"
                />
            <TextView
                android:shadowColor="#ffff"

                android:shadowRadius="1"
                android:textSize="3mm"

                android:id="@+id/upper_search_text"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textColor="#3951a3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Search"
                />
            <View
                android:layout_below="@+id/upper_search_text"
                android:id="@+id/line"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#603913"

                />
            <TextView
                android:shadowColor="#ffff"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="1"
                android:id="@+id/bigtext"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/line"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="3.5mm"
                android:textColor="#603913"
                android:text="Can I Park Here ?"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginLeft="2mm"
                android:layout_marginRight="2mm"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bigtext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/house_number"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="10dp"
                        android:hint="Number"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:layout_weight=".75"
                        android:layout_width="12mm"
                        android:layout_height="3.5mm"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"/>
                    <EditText

                        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                        android:id="@+id/street_full_name"
                        android:textSize="10dp"
                        android:hint="Street Full Name"
                        android:layout_weight=".75"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="1mm"
                        android:layout_width="30mm"
                        android:layout_height="3.5mm"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"/>

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <TextView

                        android:shadowColor="#ffff"
                        android:shadowDx="1"
                        android:shadowDy="1"
                        android:shadowRadius="1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="1mm"
                        android:text="Number"
                        android:layout_weight=".75"
                        android:layout_width="10mm"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#603913"
                        android:textSize="2mm"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        />
                    <TextView

                        android:shadowColor="#ffff"
                        android:shadowDx="1"
                        android:shadowDy="1"
                        android:shadowRadius="1"
                        android:textSize="2mm"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="#603913"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Street Full  Name"
                        android:layout_weight=".75"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="7mm"
                        android:layout_width="28mm"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView

                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                    android:id="@+id/datepiker"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:hint="   02/10/17 8:27PM"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="3.5mm" />
                <TextView
                    android:shadowColor="#ffff"
                    android:shadowDx="1"
                    android:shadowDy="1"
                    android:shadowRadius="1"
                    android:textSize="1mm"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#603913"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Date(MM/DD/YY)  Hour(1-12)AM/PM"

                    />
                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_bg"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    ><!-- <<<-&#45;&#45;&#45;&#45;&#45;&#45;added this line

                   >-->
                   <!-- android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"-->

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="fill"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/result"
                        android:textColor="#323232"



                        />
                </ScrollView>

                />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:textSize="2mm"
                    android:shadowColor="#ffff"
                    android:shadowDx="1"
                    android:shadowDy="1"
                    android:shadowRadius="1"
                    android:textColor="#030000"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="For more detail information,"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    />
                <TextView
                    android:textSize="2mm"
                    android:shadowColor="#ffff"
                    android:shadowDx="1"
                    android:shadowDy="1"
                    android:shadowRadius="1"
                    android:textColor="#030000"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Please refer to map symbols."
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>




    <!--end send box-->

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/starlayout"
        android:background="#ffff"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="3mm"
            android:id="@+id/topheader"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enter you Location name"
            />
<EditText

    android:id="@+id/loc_name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topheader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/loc_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <TextView
android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="Save"
                android:textColor="#c9b8a6"
                android:layout_below="@+id/loc_name"
                android:id="@+id/saveloc"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:textSize="3mm"

                android:layout_height="40dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:textColor="#c9b8a6"
                android:text="Cancl"

                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/canclebtn"
                android:textSize="3mm"
                />



        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>




    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/gerag"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_width="7mm"
        android:layout_height="7mm"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/garage_btn"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My MainActivity XML code **

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    tools:context="com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10mm"
        tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutStyle"

        android:background="#f4f8f9"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
   <!-- <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_tab_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/tab_layout"
        >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>-->
    <com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.Model.NonSwipeableViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_tab_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/tab_layout"
        >
    </com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.Model.NonSwipeableViewPager>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is the bottom view where home,map and all those buttons is that is also your view??

Comment: tab layout in my main activity.And Map view is a fragment .and i am facing problem while showing a view of send box in map fragment .;

Comment: share the xml of your MapFragment where you want to show your send box view

Comment: sumit thanks i uploaded my Mapfragment xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    tools:context="com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.MainActivity">



    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10mm"
        tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutStyle"

        android:background="#f4f8f9"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

//code for Sendbox now it'll be always on top on tablayout
     <include layout="@layout/sandbox"
                android:id="@+id/sandBoxlayout"/>
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks summit. for giving me your valuable time  .But please can you see again my picture of goal .what i exactly want

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong you want your sandbox layout on top of your Mapview but with the current layout.xml your layout is getting cut in the bottom. You want your sendbox on top of those bottom buttons??

Comment: No you slightly wrong. i want to my sendbox layout on over tablayout  .that is on bottom.please see again my picture

Comment: oh ok then the include part remove it from fragment.xml and include it in your tabactivity.xml

Comment: please let me sure .have you again seen my goal picture ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzNll.jpg

Comment: I think you're not getting my point share your tabActivity xml where you have written code for the bottom tab that is overlapping your sendBox layout

Comment: ok thanks  .now i need to create sendbox.xml.file and call it ?

Comment: it's there on the top just put it inside a xml file

Comment: <include layout="@layout/sandbox" its giving error on mainactivity

Comment: Use the name of xml file in which you have written your sendbox layout code. I just provided a dummy name in my include part

Comment: ok friend .now i am going to run program and then tell you wait

Comment: oh man so sorry I didn't see it earlier put the layout below Tablayout I have edited the code. Silly mistake on my side :P

Comment: no friend now my Tablayout is disappear and view still is cutting from bottom

Comment: it might be disappearing behind the sendbox layout or there might be implementation problem at your side, because I implemented it and it is working for me. If it still doesn't work do one thing create another layout for landscape mode and make necessary changes there. That way you can be sure where the problem is.

Comment: ok friend again thanks for giving me your time .i will tell you after implemented your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ScrollView** as a parent view.

Comment: Thanks for response. tab layout in my main activity.And Map view is a fragment .and i am facing problem while showing a view of send box in map fragment ..please see actual pic what i need

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Framelayout. You can easily overlap two layouts in Framelayout.

As android developer's site:

**You can add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute. 
Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top. The size of the FrameLayout is the size of its largest child (plus padding), visible or not (if the FrameLayout's parent permits).**